# R Unexpected Error in merge multiple objects into one【Error: vector::reserve】

Tags: r

Environment: Remote Linux server, R4.1.3, using conda for environment management, and radian for editing

The goal is to merge multiple objects into one, which might take up to about 400GB of memory during the process. (The server has 1T of memory)

However, after merging 4-5 objects, the program threw an Error: vector::reserve and then the program was interrupted.
What's most frustrating is that I checked and this doesn't seem to be an R language error.
Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

The functions and packages should not be problematic as they are commonly used.

```
library(Seurat)
library(pryr)

log_file <- "/home/hanc/Mycode/merge_log1120.txt"

data <- readRDS("/home/hanc/Mycode/data20.RDS")

merged.data <- data [11][[1]][[1]]

for (i in 12:20) {

sink(log_file, append=TRUE)

#CORE
merged.data <- merge (merged.data, y = data [i][[1]][[1]], project = "MergedData")

#log
  # mem
  mem_used_gb <- mem_used() / 1024^3
  
  # time
  beijing_time <- Sys.time()
  attr(beijing_time, "tzone") <- "Asia/Shanghai"
  
  # output
  cat(paste("第 ", formatC(i, width = -2, format = "d", flag = "0"), " 个对象已完成，当前内存占用为 ", 
            formatC(mem_used_gb, digits = 2, format = "f"), " GB，当前时间为 ", beijing_time, "\n"))

}

#Save
saveRDS(data, file = "/home/hanc/Mycode/data1120.RDS")
```

Comment: I believe objects in R are limited to a maximum length of 2^32 - 1 (about 4.29 billion) elements. If you are working with very large objects, this might be the source of the error, even if your code is correct and you have adequate memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I plan to manually merge each object one by one to see if it will hit the limit.

Comment: Can you check the version of your installed `Matrix` package? Use: `packageVersion("Matrix")`

Comment: 1.6.0.       
there was a bug in 1.5.1,so I updated it a few weeks ago